# Apache won't start with systemd

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, systemd, apache2

I've run into an issue where enabling the PHP driver for MS SQL Server [1] causes Apache httpd to timeout after three minutes when started with systemd (`systemctl start httpd`). Apache functions fine if started directly (`httpd -X`). The systemctl error is:

> Job for httpd.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

If I disable the PHP/MSSQL driver, the problem goes away.

This is RedHat 7.5 and SELinux is in "permissive" mode.

The linke below has relevant log files from running `echo $(date) && systemctl restart httpd`. Date echoed was `Mon Jun 25 11:46:25 CDT 2018`, so logs start at that point. Estimated failure time at 11:49:25 since it's been timing out 3 minutes after running `restart httpd`. Note that there were no entries in the PHP error log, so that's not included. Apache `LogLevel` set to `debug`.

Log files: https://gist.github.com/jamesmontalvo3/50cfaa2b2cee966917fc96e3c6784887

Since the logs above don't appear to show anything useful, I also ran `strace -ff -o /tmp/st2 -s 5000 systemctl start httpd`. The output of the the six stack traced processes can be found here: https://gist.github.com/jamesmontalvo3/89f5e3897c1e2b71b68818215f220477. However, I also don't see any errors here.

How can I determine how to fix this without any useful error messages? Or is there something that I'm just missing?

I've posted this issue on the PHP/MSSQL driver's GitHub [2] and on the Apache mailing list [3].

Refs:

[1] https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql

[2] https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/805

[3] http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/201807.mbox/%3CCANkjp2rF2beFWWaEpLSouCOc+txzdGh0rihLYz4s4-uWQmOoOg@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: [Mon Jun 25 11:48:31.921182 2018] [core:warn] [pid 11956] AH00098: pid file /run/httpd/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

Have you checked no istance of httpd is already running?

Comment: Enabling MSSQL driver makes the problem show up. Disabling it makes the problem go away. So I don't think the presence of the httpd.pid file is relevant. That said, I just shut down httpd, verified the httpd.pid file was not present, enabled MSSQL driver, and ran `systemctl start httpd`. The result was the same (error occurred), though I don't see the "...httpd.pid overwritten" line in httpd error_log. After the failure the httpd.pid file is present, though. So in the log files I linked, that line is probably there because the httpd.pid file gets left un-removed after the previous failed run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the important message is this one:

> Jun 25 11:47:56 server-that-fails systemd[1]: httpd.service start operation timed out. Terminating.

By default, systemd gives a service 90 seconds (`DefaultTimeoutStartSec` in `system.conf`) to start up – if it takes longer than that, the service is killed (first with SIGTERM, then after another 90 s with SIGKILL, see `systemd.kill(5)` – that’s where your three minutes are coming from). Presumably, enabling the PHP/MSSQL driver makes Apache slow enough to start that it takes longer than 90 seconds.

Try increasing the `TimeoutStartSec` of `apache.service`, e. g. `TimeoutStartSec=5min` or even `TimeoutStartSec=infinity`. You can do this with the following command:

```
systemctl set-property apache.service TimeoutStartSec=5min
```

(By the way, `strace`ing `systemctl` isn’t very useful, since `systemctl` doesn’t start the service itself – it just talks to PID1 and tells it to do stuff. To find out what is making Apache so slow, you could add `strace` to the `ExecStart=` directive of `apache.service`.)

Comment: I couldn't do the `systemctl set-property ...` command due to an error, but I manually edited `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service` and added `TimeoutStartSec=600`. This allowed httpd to start! Thanks! With the command `echo $(date) && sudo systemctl start httpd && echo $(date)` I measured it taking just over 2 minutes to start. Any idea how to determine what is causing so much lag?

Comment: Editing the file in `/usr/lib/` is a bad idea, the next package update will overwrite it. Instead, create a drop-in file in `/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/timeout.conf` and configure `TimeoutStartSec=` there (don’t forget the section as well). (That’s also what `systemctl set-property` should do, by the way – perhaps it needs `sudo`?)

Comment: To find out why Apache is so slow to start, my approach would be `strace`, either by modifying the `ExecStart=` directive (also in a drop-in file!), or by attaching to the process after it was started.

Comment: I discovered that when using `systemctl` it's checking for a user config file at `/home/.odbcinst.ini`. On most systems it'd just see that file doesn't exist and move on. However, the failing system has `/home` configured with autofs and when it checks for `/home/.odbcinst.ini` it tries to mount that file and lags for about 2 minutes before timing out. I added `HOME=/usr/share/httpd` to `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` and the problem went away since it now looks for the user config file in `/usr/share/httpd/.odbcinst.ini` and quickly moves on. Is `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` the right place to put this info?

Comment: You could also add it to the unit file (or override file) with `Environment=HOME=/usr/share/httpd`, but I don’t know about RHEL – perhaps `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` is the best place for it.

Comment: FYI, I marked this the accepted answer because it led me to the solution. Thanks for the help!